# Update Manager not working?

Tags: update-manager

```
Error when trying to access "Update Manager".
E:Opening /etc/apt/sources.list.d/private-ppa.launchpad.net_commercial-ppa-uploaders_libreoffice3.4-writerguide_ubuntu.list - ifstream::ifstream (13: Permission denied)'
```

---

```
bud@bud-Latitude-D530:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease                                
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates InRelease                        
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security InRelease                       
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise InRelease                             
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                             
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg            
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release.gpg                 
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main TranslationIndex                
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise InRelease                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release                        
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release                               
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release                          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security Release               
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release                                   
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Sources                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources             
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages                 
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner i386 Packages                 
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner TranslationIndex              
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources                     
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US                         
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources                 
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en_US
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
```

Answer (score 1):

`13: Permission denied`

That means that you have to run update-manager with root provileges.

Press [Alt]+[F2] and type

```
gksudo update-manager
```

After that you must enter your password and it's going to be ok =)